# python KeyError if key not in b.keys()

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to compare two dictionaries keys and if there is a match I want to create a new dict with the key and the values from both dictionaries, if no match I want to put value 0.

I tried the below code but I got `KeyError: 't2.large'` when I tried to print this key which is not in the first dict `a`.

```
c = dict()
a = {'m3.xlarge': 4, 't2.medium': 1, 't2.large': 1, 'm3.large': 1}
b = {'m3.xlarge': 5, 't2.medium': 1, 'm3.large': 2, 'm4.large': 1}

c = dict()
for key, value in a.items():
    if key in b.keys():
        a_key = key
        a_value = value
        b_value = b[key]
        c.setdefault(a_key,[]).append(a_value)
        c.setdefault(a_key,[]).append(b_value)
    elif key not in b.keys():
        value = b.get(key)
        print("key not in b.keys() => ", value) # key not in b.keys() =>  None
        b_value = b[key]
        print("key a not in b.keys => ", b_value) # KeyError: 't2.large'

print(c)
```

The result should be like this:

```
# c = {'m3.xlarge': [4, 5], 't2.medium': [1, 1], 't2.large': [1, 0], 'm3.large': [1, 2], 'm4.large': [0, 1]}
```

My second question, how I can do the same thing but without appending the key:value to the new dict if there is a match between the key:value from both dict.

```
't2.medium': [1, 1] will be removed because the keys:values are the same 1-1

c = {'m3.xlarge': [4, 5], 't2.large': [1, 0], 'm3.large': [1, 2], 'm4.large': [0, 1]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: because you call `b_value = b[key]` and not the `b_value = b.get(key)`.

Comment: b does not contain `t2.large` it is `m3.large`

Comment: You just need `else`, not `elif`

Comment: Your error makes sense because you tried to get the key when `if key not in b.keys():`

Comment: @DenisOlehov the result is `none` if I changed it.

Comment: @ppasler I want to get the key that is not in a dict, so its `t2.large`

Comment: why are you calling b.get(key) when you know because of the elif statement that key is not in b.keys()?

Comment: @Berlin: but later in the `elif` you write `b_value = b[key]`... But you know `key` is not part of `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is rather inefficient. The error occurs from here:

```
elif key not in b.keys():
    #...
    b_value = b[key]
```

Here you know that `key` is not an element of `b` and yet you query it.

Nevertheless, an elegant one-liner would be:

```
c = {key:[val,b.get(key,0)] for key,val in a.items()}
```

This replaces all the code you have written. However, based on your example output you perhaps need to replace it with:

```
c = {key:[val,b.get(key,0)] for key,val in a.items()}
c.update({key:[a.get(key,0),val] for key,val in b.items()})
```

or even more elegantly:

```
c = {key:[a.get(key,0),b.get(key,0)] for key in set(a)|set(b)}
```

When running this in the terminal, I get:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = {'m3.xlarge': 4, 't2.medium': 1, 't2.large': 1, 'm3.large': 1}
>>> b = {'m3.xlarge': 5, 't2.medium': 1, 'm3.large': 2, 'm4.large': 1}
>>> c = {key:[val,b.get(key,0)] for key,val in a.items()}
>>> c.update({key:[a.get(key,0),val] for key,val in b.items()})
>>> c
{'t2.medium': [1, 1], 'm3.xlarge': [4, 5], 'm3.large': [1, 2], 'm4.large': [0, 1], 't2.large': [1, 0]}
>>> c = {key:[a.get(key,0),b.get(key,0)] for key in set(a)|set(b)}
>>> c
{'t2.medium': [1, 1], 'm3.xlarge': [4, 5], 't2.large': [1, 0], 'm3.large': [1, 2], 'm4.large': [0, 1]}
```

**(2)**: to answer your second question, you can add a filter:

```
c = {key:[a.get(key,0),b.get(key,0)] for key in set(a)|set(b) if a.get(key,0) != b.get(key,0)}
```

Comment: This drops items that are in `b` but not `a`.

Comment: thanks, but  `c = {key:[val,b.get(key,0)] for key,val in a.items()}` give me `{'m3.xlarge': [4, 5], 'm3.large': [1, 2], 't2.medium': [1, 1]}` and I need something like this `{'m3.xlarge': [4, 5], 't2.medium': [1, 1], 't2.large': [1, 0], 'm3.large': [1, 2], 'm4.large': [0, 1]}`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, wow thanks!, can you please give another soultion for my second question ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a list using the keys from **both** dictionaries, you could use:

```
a = {'m3.xlarge': 4, 't2.medium': 1, 't2.large': 1, 'm3.large': 1}
b = {'m3.xlarge': 5, 't2.medium': 1, 'm3.large': 2, 'm4.large': 1}

c = dict()
for key in set(a.keys() | b.keys()):
    c[key] = [a.get(key, 0), b.get(key, 0)]
```

resulting in

```
{'t2.medium': [1, 1], 't2.large': [1, 0], 'm3.large': [1, 2], 'm4.large': [0, 1], 'm3.xlarge': [4, 5]}
```

We can incorporate the second criteria (albeit in a not particularly elegant way) and reduce down to a single line as follows:

```
c = {key: [a.get(key, 0), b.get(key, 0)] for key in set(a.keys() | b.keys()) if a.get(key, 0) != b.get(key, 0)}
```

Note: in Python 2.7 you'll need to use `a.keys() + b.keys()` rather than `a.keys() | b.keys()`

Comment: I got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_keys' and 'dict_keys'`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my apologies, didn't realise it wouldn't work in Python 3. Updated the answer now.

Comment: @asongtoruin: yeah no problem. +1 btw :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem noticed we both used the same slightly inelegant method to answer the second part, great minds think alike :)